# How can I place the customised marker in top of the Polygon in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to place the customised bubble type marker on the top of the polygon with same text on it and when polygon is visible it should display and when polygon is gone then it should not display in map. How can I place the customised marker in top of the Polygon?

```
    coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.216157, 72.920643));
    coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.207537, 73.091977));
    coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.012896, 73.012326));
    coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.036265, 72.872251));

    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.addAll(coordinateList);
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#80FFFFFF"));
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(0);
    rectOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#80ffb3ff"));
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    polygon.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place your `Marker` on the centroid of the `Polygon`:

```
List<LatLng> coordinateList = new ArrayList<>();
Polygon polygon;
Marker marker;

coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.216157, 72.920643));
coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.207537, 73.091977));
coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.012896, 73.012326));
coordinateList.add(new LatLng(19.036265, 72.872251));

PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
rectOptions.addAll(coordinateList);
rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#80FFFFFF"));
rectOptions.strokeWidth(0);
rectOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#80ffb3ff"));
polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
polygon.setVisible(true);

LatLng centroid = findCentroid(coordinateList);

IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(this);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
        icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(generator.makeIcon("Title"))).
        position(centroid).
        anchor(generator.getAnchorU(), generator.getAnchorV());
marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Here is the method to find the centroid

```
private LatLng findCentroid (List<LatLng> coordinates) {
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    for (LatLng coordinate : coordinates) {
        latitude += coordinate.latitude;
        longitude += coordinate.longitude;
    }

    return new LatLng(latitude/coordinates.size(), longitude/coordinates.size());
}
```

Then you only need to make your `Polygon` and your `Marker` visible or invisible at the same time:

```
polygon.setVisible(false);
marker.setVisible(false);
```